# how to connect frontend and backend using localhost api in c# .net projects?

Tags: c#, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

This is my API_URL:

```
VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT = "https://localhost:11187/api"
```

but when I run my backend C# (EF), API_URL is `https://localhost:44315/api/eodms`. I don't know how to connect between two, how can I change it in the backend?

I also want to know detail usage of API, can someone explain or guide some tips for my problem?

[image: this is my error]

I changed API_URL in frontend (.env file) and restart it. but it doesn't work. I use VUE js for my frontend code and C# .net for backend code.

Answer (score 0):

For you backend app - go to Visual Studio project -> folder Properties -> file launchsettings.json. You can set port number there in the *applicationUrl* property.

I'm not sure I understand correctly - you probably have a separate vue.js project. If so in that case port number can be set in vue.config.js - target property.

Perhaps [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-vue?view=vs-2022) post (part Verify ports at the bottom) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

there's another way of achieving this by having backend and frontend in the same app by using SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseSpa and proxying [your frontend] to run as default and the /api as separate endpoint in the same project. [Anton](https://youtu.be/bsSGTSxPkak) has great video on this

another way is by having them separate. first make sure your api is accessible on device level. you can use Postman or .http files. if it work. make sure the URL that env file giving is right. try console logging it. if so. try making axios requests to the endpoint of the controller you want and test from there.

in addition could you provide code for your axios call and what url your backend working on? it make solving this easier.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that wrong API URL is used in axios request. Now I fixed it.